# Spring security returns login page after submitting form

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, session, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot web application that is having issues with the authentication. After I insert a correct username and password, the form submits and returns silently to the login form.

I tried to debug and see what's going on but I cannot understand. Any help is much appreciated.

This is my security config class.

```
private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
          "/webjars/**,
          "/css/**,
          "/js/**,
          ...
}

http
            .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(100)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false)
            .expiredUrl("/expired-url")
            .sessionRegistry(securityBeans.sessionRegistry());

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll()
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
              .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
              .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
            .and()
            .logout()
              .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
              .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
              .deleteCookies("remember-me").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
              .invalidateHttpSession(true).permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
```

And the logs after submitting the forms on debugging is as follows.

```
    2020-01-28 18:10:45.398  INFO 29168 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for POST '/login':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@442276e5

servletPath:/login
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 69
cache-control: max-age=0
origin: http://localhost:8080
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
sec-fetch-user: ?1
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
referer: http://localhost:8080/login
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cookie: JSESSIONID=5F80F076DD57E7CDE52F1B24EC1BB8EF


Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  ConcurrentSessionFilter
  BasicAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]

************************************************************


Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_14_,
        user0_.created_at as created_2_14_,
        user0_.created_by as created_3_14_,

2020-01-28 18:10:46.155  INFO 29168 --- [io-8080-exec-10] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/dashboard':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@442276e5

servletPath:/dashboard
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
cache-control: max-age=0
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
sec-fetch-user: ?1
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
referer: http://localhost:8080/login
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cookie: JSESSIONID=4244FB8F7CE22B64766E8E97B6CB97EC

************************************************************


2020-01-28 18:10:46.168  INFO 29168 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/login':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@442276e5

servletPath:/login
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
cache-control: max-age=0
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
sec-fetch-user: ?1
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
referer: http://localhost:8080/login
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cookie: JSESSIONID=4244FB8F7CE22B64766E8E97B6CB97EC
```

Response sample here after it returns to the browser

```
   Request URL: http://localhost:8080/login
   Request Method: POST
   Status Code: 302 / 
 - Request Headers
   Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml; q=0.9, */*; q=0.8
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
   Accept-Language: en-US
   Cache-Control: max-age=0
   Content-Length: 109
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   Cookie: JSESSIONID=9FFAEA5655FE807B88490B358E89894D
   Host:localhost:8080
   Referer: http://localhost:8080/login
   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362
 - Response Headers
   cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
   content-length: 0
   date: Wed, 29 Jan 2020 07:20:35 GMT
   expires: 0
   location: http://localhost:8080/login
   pragma: no-cache
   server: nginx/1.16.1
   set-cookie: JSESSIONID=68D2982DB1B8022C2EBED7A05C96D67B; Path=/; HttpOnly
   x-content-type-options: nosniff
   x-frame-options: DENY
   x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

CSRF token is not bound to the request even tho it's injected in the login form
[image]

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-material" id="loginform"
                      method="post"
                      th:action="@{/login}">
                    <h3 class="text-center m-b-10">Sign In</h3>

                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input autofocus class="form-control" id="username"
                                   name="username" placeholder="Email" required type="email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input class="form-control" id="password"
                                   name="password"
                                   placeholder="Password" required
                                   th:placeholder="#{login.password.text}" type="password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="d-flex no-block align-items-center">
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input checked class="custom-control-input" id="remember-me"
                                           name="remember-me" type="checkbox">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ml-auto">
                                    <a class="text-muted" href="javascript:void(0)" id="to-recover"><i
                                            class="fas fa-lock m-r-5"></i> Forgot pwd?</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center p-b-0">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block btn-rounded text-uppercase waves-effect waves-light"
                                    type="submit">Log In
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group m-b-0">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                            Don't have an account? <a
                                class="text-info m-l-5"
                                th:href="@{/sign-up}"><b>Sign
                            Up</b></a> <a class="float-right" th:href="@{/}">Home</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Do you have any info about the response?

Comment: I have added a sample response I get after it returns to the login page. And when the issue occurs, the jsessionid cookie received is always different on page reload.

Comment: Do you know which filter is throwing an exception/denying the request? Perhaps it's BasicAuthenticationFilter

Comment: It doesn't say that much as to which filter is causing this and yes I use the BasicAuthenticationFilter

Comment: Actually the exception is thrown after a csrf token is reported invalid

Comment: Once you encounter the login page after entering your credentials as you describe, what happens if you manually try to navigate to a protected page via URL bar? Do you get a login prompt again?

Comment: It redirects me back to the login page and this issue happens more often after I deploy to AWS using the Elastic Beanstalk and also have a load balancer configured.

Comment: Can you provide all the string values of the constants "IndexControllerConstant.*" , "IndexControllerConstant.*" and "SecurityConfig.*" in your config?

Comment: I have updated the code with the string values instead of the constants.

Comment: Can you set up the log level of the package `org.spring.framework.security`to TRACE. That will give you the complete information about what filter is rejecting your request.

Comment: Could you show us your html login form?

Comment: Added my login form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by not using a secured cookie and httpOnly settings.
I had to enable stickiness based on a response from aws support.

"You can use the sticky session feature, which enables the load balancer to bind a user's session to a specific instance. This ensures that all requests from the user during the session are sent to the same instance. Please try enabling "Session stickiness" under the load balancer configuration for your application"

After these settings, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove httpBasic when you have your login page. I think both securities apply in your config.

```
.and()
//Delete this line
.httpBasic();
```

Comment: I did it but it's still behaving the same way.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `CsrfTokenRepository` to persist the CSRF Token either in a cookie (`XSRF-TOKEN`) or in HttpSession, a request should pass a token in a header named `X-XSRF-TOKEN`.

Pass XSRF token value in this custom header. Something like this:

```
--header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN: 3993871d-d15b-4932-a74f-744769132d86'
```

Comment: To token is already passed in the header if I don't disable csrf()